# NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object on a SerialPort.ReadLine() method

Tags: c#, serial-port, grasshopper

When running the code below, I get the following `NullReferenceException`. What am I missing?

```
 System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=Silkworm
  StackTrace:
       at UnhandledExceptionLogger.UnhandledDomainException(Object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args)
```

Code:

```
   //Fields
            List<string> myReceivedLines;

            //subscriber method for the port.DataReceived Event
            private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
            {
                SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
                while (sp.BytesToRead > 0)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        myReceivedLines.Add(sp.ReadLine());
                    }
                    catch (TimeoutException)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }



            protected override void SolveInstance(IGH_DataAccess DA)
            {

                string selectedportname = default(string);
                DA.GetData(1, ref selectedportname);
                int selectedbaudrate = default(int);
                DA.GetData(2, ref selectedbaudrate);
                bool connecttodevice = default(bool);
                DA.GetData(3, ref connecttodevice);


                SerialPort port = new SerialPort(selectedportname, selectedbaudrate, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One); //Create the serial port
                port.DtrEnable = true;   //enables the Data Terminal Ready (DTR) signal during serial communication (Handshaking)

                port.Open();             //Open the port


                if ((port.IsOpen) && (connecttodevice == true))
                {
                    port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
                    DA.SetDataList(0, myReceivedLines);
                }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
myReceivedLines = new List<string>()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I get the following message: `Invalid token = in class, struct, or interface member declaration`

Comment: How are you initializing myReceivedLines?

Answer (score 3):

`myReceivedLines` is declared, but never assigned a value, so it remains null. You probably want to initialise it, like:

```
List<string> myReceivedLines = new List<string>();
```

Then, you can proceed to use it.

Comment: Just to let you know.. you should remove var myReceivedLines as that won't compile. You can't use var to declare fields.

Comment: @LewsTherin Ah, indeed. The odd formatting and (valid) lack of an explicit access modifier must have thrown me.